# is it possible to concatenate contents of first arraylist to second arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

is it possible to concatenate contents of first set of array to second set of array. like for example, given contents are:

```
 tempc = [a, b, c, d, e, f] and tempe = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and i wanna end up something like this:

```
enter code here tempf = [a1, b2, c3, d4 e5, f6]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick, even when the two Lists are of different size:

```
public static List<String> concatenate(List<String> l1, List<String> l2) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int min = Math.min(l1.size(), l2.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < min; ++i)
        result.add(l1.get(i) + l2.get(i));

    for (int i = min; i < l1.size(); ++i)
        result.add(l1.get(i));
    for (int i = min; i < l2.size(); ++i)
        result.add(l2.get(i));
    return result;
}
```

**Example code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("b");
    list1.add("c");
    list2.add("1");
    list2.add("2");
    list2.add("3");
    System.out.println(concatenate(list1, list2));
}
```

**Output**

```
[a1, b2, c3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `ArrayList`, and assuming that both inputs have the same size:

```
ArrayList<String> tempc = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
ArrayList<String> tempe = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
ArrayList<String> tempf = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < tempc.size(); i++) {
    tempf.add(tempc.get(i) + tempe.get(i)); 
}
```

Comment: OP was asking about ArrayLists, not arrays (at least according to the question title).

Answer (score 0):

`myConcatArray.set(index, myArray1.get(index)+myArray2.get(index));` if you are using just primitive data types.

However; if you are using objects and trying to combine objects you may need to create a custom class with some methods that handle how data between two objects get combined together.